# Appending a dictionary of dictionaries with another dictionary of dictionaries not getting order correct

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 4 python dictionaries where the value of each key is another dictionary:

```
a={'a': {'e': 4}}
b={'b': {'f': 5}}
c={'c': {'g': 6}}
d={'d': {'h': 7}}
```

I want to merge dictionaries a, b, c and d together so that I have one final dictionary that looks like:

```
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'b': {'f': 5}, 'c': {'g': 6}, 'd': {'h': 7}}
```

where the order of the parent dictionary is in the order in which I add each original dictionary.

So I created an empty dictionary and did this:

```
x={} #create empty dictionary
x.update(a) #update with first dictionary
print x
x.update(b) #update with second dictionary
print x
x.update(c) #update with third dictionary
print x
x.update(d) #update with forth dictionary
print x
```

The result is this:

```
{'a': {'e': 4}}
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'b': {'f': 5}}
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'c': {'g': 6}, 'b': {'f': 5}}
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'c': {'g': 6}, 'b': {'f': 5}, 'd': {'h': 7}}
```

I am not sure why, after the third update, that c is added to x between a and b. And then after the forth update, d somehow gets added at the end. It seems random.

Keep in mind, that sorted will not work. The above is an example of what I want and my keys may not always be in alphabetical order. I simple want the order in which I added each dictionary.

Edit: This is for python 2.7, but appreciate answers for 3.6 as I will be migrating a tool from 2 to 3 in the near future.

Answer (score 5):

You can just unpack each dict into one (in python3.6+ it will retain order of insertion):

```
>>> {**a, **b, **c, **c, **d}
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'b': {'f': 5}, 'c': {'g': 6}, 'd': {'h': 7}}
```

And in python 3.9+ you could use the merge operator:

```
>>> a | b | c | d
{'a': {'e': 4}, 'b': {'f': 5}, 'c': {'g': 6}, 'd': {'h': 7}}
```

**EDIT**

This also works for `OrderedDict`s. As you are using python 2.7 this will retain order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(**a, **b, **c, **d)
OrderedDict([('a', {'e': 4}), ('b', {'f': 5}), ('c', {'g': 6}), ('d', {'h': 7})])
```

Answer (score 1):

"A dictionary is a collection which is unordered, changeable and indexed." - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp, so its only natural that they might not be in the desired order.
Use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module if you want your dictionary to keep the order in which keys are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have no sense of order in Python versions earlier than version 3.6.

Use an `OrderedDict` if you want to preserve the insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {"a": {"e": 4}}
b = {"b": {"f": 5}}
c = {"c": {"g": 6}}
d = {"d": {"h": 7}}

x.update(a)
x.update(b)
x.update(c)
x.update(d)

assert x.keys() == ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```